# Limit number of column

Tags: php, html, css, loops, while-loop

this is example of my code..

```
<table>
 <tr>

  while($report && !$report ->EOF) {
  <td>$name</td>
  $report ->MoveNext();
  }

 </tr>
</table>
```

i've a looping column.. my problem is, how to force the column or limit the number of column so that one row can hold only 5 column.. if more than 5 column, the column will go to next page. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific: do you want to insert a page break after each 5th column? Use [`page-break-after`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)

Comment: You just add a counter variable, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php
        $count = 5;
        while($report && !$report ->EOF && $count > 0) {
            echo "<td>$name</td>";
            $report ->MoveNext();
            $count--;
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just added a simple counter to the while loop. By increasing the count you can make more columns appear

Comment: thank you for your answer.. if i have 10 column, but i set the no of column to 5, where are the other 5 column goes? how to make it appear to the next page by using style="page-break-after: always;"